# Unable to parse JSON with empty array/objects

Tags: c#, json, json.net, deserialization

Trying the parse this json file and it seems to be getting stuck on empty objects and arrays.

> {"Unexpected character encountered while parsing value: [. Path 'notes'."}

```
{
   "id":null,
   "phone":null,
   "name":" ",
   "email":null,
   "address":null,
   "assignee":null,
   "notes":[

   ],
   "created_at":null,
   "items":{
      "0":{
         "minimized":false,
         "sku":{
            "partner_id":null,
            "type_id":0,
            "errors":{

            }
         }
        }
    }
}
```

**CLASSES**

```
public class RootObject
{
    public string id { get; set; }
    public string phone { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string email { get; set; }
    public string address { get; set; }
    public string assignee { get; set; }
    public string notes { get; set; }
    public string created_at { get; set; }
    public Items items { get; set; }
}

public class Items
{
    public bool minimized { get; set; }
    public Sku sku { get; set; }
}

public class Sku
{
    public int partner_id { get; set; }
    public int type_id { get; set; }
    public Errors errors { get; set; }
}


public class Errors
{
}
```

The issue appears to be with handling the Notes and Errors property, I've tried to use the following settings as per a few other SO posts but nothing has worked and I am not sure how to get this to deserialize into an object.

```
RootObject o = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(json, new JsonSerializerSettings
{
    MissingMemberHandling = MissingMemberHandling.Ignore,
    NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore
});
```

Perhaps someone can help me out because it seems to me JSON.net should be able to handle these properties?

Comment: So I think in this case Notes should be an IList or something similar. Please check.

Comment: In your POCO `notes` is of type string and in json its an array. Correct this mismatch and you are good to go.

Comment: ok managed to get notes working, but errors is still an issue.. it's an empty object {} in the json, how can I get that to deserialize correctly?

Comment: @devfunkd did you use my classes? the "0":{ part is most probably the reason that you have got a null in sku

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Here's a working dotNetFiddle: https://dotnetfiddle.net/Lnkojw

### Here's the output.

[image]

**NOTE:** I put in sample values in your json for your null values so you can see that it is working)

Your class definitions (autogenerated from http://json2csharp.com/ ) need to be modified as shown below.

```
public class RootObject
{
    public string id { get; set; }
    public string phone { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string email { get; set; }
    public string address { get; set; }
    public string assignee { get; set; }
    public List<string> notes { get; set; }
    public string created_at { get; set; }
    public Dictionary<int,Item> items { get; set; }
}

public class Item
{
    public bool minimized { get; set; }
    public Sku sku { get; set; }
}

public class Sku
{
    public int partner_id { get; set; }
    public int type_id { get; set; }
    [JsonIgnore]
    public object errors { get; set; }
}
```

Since you have stated in comments that `Errors` will always be empty, I removed that redundant `Errors` class you had, with no properties or members. I also set the `errors` member in the `Sku` class to be `object` type in case you get values in future. Finally I set this `errors` property to `[JsonIgnore]` so json.net will ignore it for serialization / deserialization

Also `Items` appears to be `Dictionary` with an `int` for key and an `Item` for Value. So I have changed the definition there also.

Here's the code that deserializes and prints out the values.

```
using System;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        string json = @"{
                           ""id"":1,
                           ""phone"":""415-000-1234"",
                           ""name"":"" "",
                           ""email"":null,
                           ""address"":null,
                           ""assignee"":null,
                           ""notes"":[

                           ],
                           ""created_at"":null,
                           ""items"":{
                              ""0"":{
                                 ""minimized"":false,
                                 ""sku"":{
                                    ""partner_id"":21,
                                    ""type_id"":44,
                                    ""errors"":{

                                    }
                                 }
                                }
                            }
                        }";


        Console.WriteLine("Deserializing json...");
        RootObject o = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(json, new JsonSerializerSettings
        {
            MissingMemberHandling = MissingMemberHandling.Ignore,
            NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore
        });     
        Console.WriteLine("Success!");
        Console.WriteLine("id #: {0}",o.id);
        Console.WriteLine("phone #: {0}",o.phone);
        foreach (var item in o.items)
        {           
            Console.WriteLine("  Item #: {0}",item.Key);
            if (item.Value != null)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("    SKU: partner_id: {0}",item.Value.sku.partner_id);    
                Console.WriteLine("    SKU: type_id: {0}",item.Value.sku.type_id);  
            }
        }       
    }
}
```

And once again, here's the output. You can see the json values properly deserialized.

[image]

**PRO TIPS:**

1. Use a sample json that has values for as many fields as possible, so that http://json2csharp.com/ can generate the proper classes
2. Whenever you have a nameless property like the `items` in your json,you will likely need to inspect what http://json2csharp.com/ generated and modify it to be a `Dictionary` or a `NameValuePair` or `KeyValuePair` or something else. It is on a case by case basis. In other words, for **99%** of well designed json, you can "plug and play" with http://json2csharp.com/ , for the remaining **1%** you will have to customize the classes generated, or your serialization code or both.

Answer (score 0):

The issue seems to be that in your auto-properties for RootObject, you have the `notes` property listed as a `string` rather than `string[]` - if notes are indeed an array of strings, your JSON snippet doesn't show that.

You should also be able to use a `List<string>` for notes, if you would prefer that.

Comment: Ok string[] worked but my Sku object is null now, any ideas why?

Comment: Could you update your original post with a complete example of the JSON data? Including errors?

Comment: I did, Errors is an empty object as it never populates from the datasource. I don't control the 3rd party data, just been told it's always an empty/null value as it's not used anymore.

Comment: If it's no longer used, do you need to have it in your model? If you just remove it from your class, it shouldn't attempt to map it either.